# Restart MediaCapture when app comes back into focus

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a Windows 8 app (C#) using the `MediaCapture` class (`Windows.Media.Capture`) to show a webcam feed, I'm trying to restart the preview when the app has lost and then come back into focus (e.g. by clicking in the top left screen corner to another app, then clicking again to come back to my app).

How I'm trying to restart the preview right now is:

```
Application.Current.Resuming += (sender, o) => StartVideo(video);
Application.Current.Suspending += (sender, args) => StopVideo();

internal async void StartVideo(CaptureElement e)
{
    try
    {
        this.stream = new MediaCapture();
        await this.stream.InitializeAsync();
        e.Source = this.stream;
        await this.stream.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        new MessageDialog("Unable to start the video capture.").ShowAsync();
    }
}

internal async void StopVideo()
{
    try
    {
        await stream.StopPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

But, the `Resuming` and `Suspending` events don't seem to fire in the example I describe above. Is this not "suspending" an app? If so, what is it/what events should I be on the lookout for?

Alternatively, should I, instead of using a long-running "preview" to display the webcam, use one of the `this.stream.StartRecord...` methods?

**EDIT:** If I fire the events manually using Visual Studio's Suspend/Resume button (on the Debug Location toolbar), the functionality works as desired (the video restarts when the app is resumed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things wrong:

- You should avoid `async void`; use `async Task` for all methods except event handlers.
- For "command" events such as `Suspending`, use the deferral provided by `args.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral` if you have an `async` event handler.

Comment: What would I return if I change either method from async void async Task? The only awaited call in both method returns void.

Further, getting a suspension doesn't seem like the problem - the code gets executed if I use Visual Studio's Suspend/Resume button. But, it doesn't get executed if I do the action I described in the question.

Comment: An `async Task` method doesn't return a value; you just change the return type. [Switching away from an app doesn't (immediately) suspend it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx); you probably want `VisibilityChanged`.

Comment: `VisibilityChanged` did the trick, and thanks for the tip on `async Task`!